# HTML cache manifest download all files

Tags: html, cache-manifest

It seems that if the cache manifest on the server changes it will re-download everything in file? Is there any way to only make it re-download some of the files? If I only make code fixes to a script and then update the manifest (say just put a timestamp comment in it) to force local copies to see a change has been made, I might not want images re-downloaded that haven't changed but still need to be in the manifest. Is there a way to get more precision around this or is it an all or nothing thing?

Answer (score 2):

From what i've expreienced, updating the cache manifest doesn't explicitly download all the content again, but rather checks if they've been modified. So if there are 10 items in your cache manifest and you were to update a single file (and also the manifest file), then each file would be checked for modification, and depending on how they are being served (CDN?) they should be returning a 304 Not Modified, and thus not be downloaded again.